# How to find out what WSGI server is used in a shared host

Tags: python, wsgi, asgi

I have a shared host with LiteSpeed server. After messing around with cPanel, I found out Phusion Passenger is used. Is it possible to know what WSGI/ASGI server is used without consulting my service provider, possibly through terminal or a Python script?

Comment: If you have terminal access, can you run `ps aux -Hw` and get a complete process list? You should see it there.

Comment: For some reason there are just two processes listed.

Comment: It's probably running in a container. What are the processes?

Comment: `/bin/bash -l` and `ps aux -Hw`.